# Возможно ли использовать две переменные в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как в **jQuery** использовать сразу две переменные, а не писать каждый код для каждой переменной?
Заранее спасибо!

```
var maps_au = $('.maps_1');
var maps_na = $('.maps_2');``
```

Например:

```
$(maps_au,maps_na).hide();
```

а не:

```
maps_au.hide();
maps_na.hide();
```

Comment: собственно в первых 2х строчках вы и обьявили 2ве переменные

Comment: Простите, неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Можно ли использовать эти две переменные в одну строчку? Чтобы меньше кода писать, например.

Comment: там есть кнопка `править` воспользуйтесь ею для редактирования вопроса, чтобы не вводить людей в заблюждение

Comment: var maps = $('[class*=maps_]'); maps.hide();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется ты хочешь это:

```
var maps_au = '.maps_1';
var maps_na = '.maps_2';
$(maps_au + ', ' + maps_na).hide();
```

Об этом написано тут: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/, что *Jquery* допускает мультиселекторность

Comment: @Александр это Вы неаккуратно код скопировали

Comment: @Александр что именно не работает? Ты так написал как в ответе?  https://jsfiddle.net/bu6o3g7y/

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Александр тут используются текстовые переменные, а не переменные jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var maps_au = $('.maps_1');
var maps_na = $('.maps_2');
$.merge(maps_au, maps_na).hide();
```

```css
.block { height: 20px; }
.maps_1 { background-color: green; }
.maps_2 { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block maps_1"></div>
<div class="block maps_2"></div>
```

Либо создать отдельный набор, в котором будем хранить обе выборки:

```js
var allMaps = $();
var maps_au = $('.maps_1');
var maps_na = $('.maps_2');
allMaps.add(maps_au).add(maps_na).hide();
```

```css
.block { height: 20px; }
.maps_1 { background-color: green; }
.maps_2 { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block maps_1"></div>
<div class="block maps_2"></div>
```

P.S. Да, я знаю, что это странно, когда результат выполнения кода выглядит как ничто.

Answer (score 1):

Вы и так их объявили и инициализировали. Надо правильно использовать.

```
var maps_au = $('.maps_1');
var maps_na = $('.maps_2');
maps_au.hide();
maps_na.hide();
```

Comment: А так делать, как я понимаю, нельзя? неужели нет способа уменьшить написание кода?(maps_au,maps_na).hide();

Comment: @Александр, можно: `$('.maps_1, .maps_2').hide();`

Comment: А есть ли возможность с объявленными переменными такое сделать? (maps_au и maps_na)